# pipline always trigered surprisely

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I run 3 pipeline builds which need approval on jenkins where there are only 2 executors. So if the first and the second build are not approved, the third build will wait, meanwhile the strange things will happen that the third build will be triggered once per minute(I set scm poll "* * * * * "and these three builds all triggered by code commit). How can I fix this?

this is my pipeline script

```
pipeline{
agent any
stages{
    stage('Build'){
        steps{
            echo 'Building123'
        }
    }
    stage('Test'){
        steps{
            echo 'Testing12'

        }
    }
    stage('Approve'){  
        steps{
                script{
                    input message: 'Do you want to deploy?'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy-Staging1'){
        steps{
            echo 'Deploy-Staging1'
            echo 'Deploy-Staging2'
            }
    }

    stage('Deploy-Production'){
        steps{
            echo 'Deploy-Production'

        }
    }
}
}
```

build 47, 48 and 49 is triggered by commit, build50 and others are triggered accidentally

jenkins build screen

[image]

this is  the polling log of build 54

```html
Polling Log
View as plain text
This page captures the polling log that triggered this build.

Started on Feb 27, 2018 1:52:00 AM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision f0a868f03cba928812b8505afbfd86034605f96e (origin/master)
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git ls-remote -h https://github.com/yuzp1996/test-approve # timeout=10
Found 1 remote heads on https://github.com/yuzp1996/test-approve
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/master is: 6a9a5f9ef27350be97978e225bef1dda7272f7ef
Done. Took 5.3 sec
Changes found
```

Comment: I'm confused.  You set the pipeline to perform an scm poll every minute, but you don't want it to run once per minute?  Is your goal to have Jenkins notify you that there are changes, but then you want to manually decide when to run the pipeline?

Comment: Hello！ I am sorry I did not make it clear. The pipelines triggered need to be approved and there are only two executors. So if the first and the second pipeline are not approved, the third pipeline will wait, meanwhile the strange things will happen that  the third pipeline will be triggered once per minute.(These pipelines all triggered by code commit). Thanks very much!

Comment: can you share your pipeline script for the 3 pipeline ? and the log to see what trigger it ...

Comment: Ok! But to be honest my pipeline script is very simple.I will show my pipeline script in my post. I think this is a bug of jenkins

Comment: I think when I commit code the jenkins executor will only check the builds which are building. However the build in building queue will not be checked. So jenkins executor will think the third build was not exist and it will build again and once again.  This is a logic error for jenkins build